# solve polynomial equation in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to solve
[image]

for r. I found MORT() function in SAS, but I don't know how I could solve it in PL/SQL.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result for a couple of cases.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=irr-calculations-in-sql-or-plsql

Comment: Removed the SAS tag, there's no SAS component to this question.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Power function.

```
SELECT (a * r * power(1 + r, n)) / (power(1+r, n) - 1) from dual
```

For example, to calculate the interest on a 100,000 loan at 10% interest over 20 years

```
select (100000 * 0.1/12 * power(1 + 0.1/12, 20*12))/ (power(1 + 0.1/12, 20*12) - 1) from dual
```

Comment: Yes, this is annuity. But I want to find interest rate r given annuity p.